# Approach to high performance UI of help search travel website package product with multiple hotels and flights and other products

Tags: angularjs, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I have a travel website built in ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF5 with package product. Each package product has multiple set of hotels and flights defined for each day of package.

Currently, when user searches for particular package price by my application I call webservice of multiple hotel and flight suppliers to get rates and calculate the total package price after getting all the rates from suppliers.

Problem: During get rates for package my site performance is too slow as I wait to get price for all products added in package from supplier webservices for each flight and each hotel and then update the UI with the details.

I am thinking may be to use SignalR to get rates for hotel/ flight and update UI using angular to show the fastest returned response first. Once, I get all prices then will calculate total package price.

Need help in approach to follow to get high performance (less than 25 secs) in this case.

Thanks,

Vivek

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your use case for SignalR. If I understand correct at the moment it is slow becuase you wait for response from external services and then only show once all promises are resolved. Is that correct or you show as you get results from service and then update UI as soon as you get more prices?

Comment: I update at last after getting all the results from webserivces, I haven't implemented SignalR yet so no real time update of UI is being done currently. Currently, its a normal apporach and i use Tasks to call webservices of hotels and flights to get results by multithreading
@FarrukhSubhani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this approach used by most of such services that rely on external services to reply and then show best by price or availability or rating:

1. Take user search params and on your server or client side you may need to format them to get them ready for external providers.
2. SignalR hub can be used to send above params to server and now hub would wait for server to reply back and lets say run a simple call back (addToResults) function.
3. On Server you will use existing method of fetching results and probably have parallel calls running to different services. Once a call return results you can simply call a function on hub with Results passed to it. You may need to format results to a standard format.
4. On Client side the hub would know addToResults function need to be triggered and it would add obtained results to UI. You can use angular or jQuery or anything to populate UI with latest results or sort them etc.
5. During this time if you want you can also have different function on hub to update UI for example how many total services you are using, how many have been done and how many user should wait for.

Ideally time to wait should be reduced to service that takes most time and bit of extra meta you send and get from your server however it would be quite an improvement over what you are doing now.

Without signalR you can do something where you already know x amount of services need to be queried and you can simply do ajax calls to different functions on your server which would in return give you result of each service. When you get result from any service simply append it to results and carry on. This would also reduce time and start showing results as soon as first ajax call has returned and can also track how many left etc.

Most of the time speed would be limited to external service response so earlier you give your user indication of response from quicker service it would look speedy however if user is looking for highest rated company providing lowest price and it is returned last the wait time is only the wait it took for longest call and not accumulated wait of all calls.

Comment: I think I will try this approach first.
"you already know x amount of services need to be queried and you can simply do ajax calls to different functions on your server which would in return give you result of each service".
After all ajax calls finished I will make another ajax call to server function to validate if all product rates returned or not. Thanks a lot!